# Fetch Data in a form through Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making an auto-complete form, in which user enter only the id and the whole information related to that id comes in other field. I am using ajax and Laravel 5.4. The Data is coming in alert but how i can insert data in input fields of a form. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

    var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
       //var id=$(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
              url: '/inquiryVendor',
              type: "Get",
              data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, // the value of input having id vid
               success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed

            alert(response); console.log(response);


        }
            });
    });
</script>
```

this is my controller:

```
public function VendorDetail(Request $request)
    {

    $id= $request->id;

      $data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * from bp where id = '$id'"));
      echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

here is my console.log response:

```
[{"id":37,"card_name":"Maka Furniture Co.,Ltd ","trade_type":"Manufacturer","address":"Xinzhang development zones,Shengfang town,Hebei province.","fc":"121AC209","status":0,"created_at":"2018-10-10 10:02:27","user":"admin"}]
```

here is the screenshot of response:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all data in single input you can use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

        var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
           //var id=$(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                  url: '/inquiryVendor',
                  type: "Get",
                  dataType: 'json',//this will expect a json response
                  data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, 
                   success: function(response){ 
                        $("#inputfieldid").val(response);     
            }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

or if you want on different input field you can do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

    var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
       //var id=$(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
              url: '/inquiryVendor',
              type: "Get",
              dataType: 'json',//this will expect a json response
              data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, 
               success: function(response){ 
                    $("#inputfieldid1").val(response.id); 
                    $("#inputfieldid2").val(response.2ndcolumnName);
                    $("#inputfieldid").val(response.3rdcolumnName); 

        }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: by adding dataType json, How i Will return result in controller. right now i am returning in echo json_encode($data)

Comment: I am getting values by using   $("#inputfieldid").val(response);  but not  $("#inputfieldid1").val(response.id);

Comment: sir i have given $("#inputfieldid1").val(response.id);  this as a example put your column name instead of  .id in val(response.id) here

Comment: Yes I know I have column name id in my table

Comment: provide your json data response screen shot

Comment: by adding dataType: 'json', I get nothing

Comment: if you add dataType :'json' you don't need to parse the data later in your jquery after success

Comment: see the screen shot above

Comment: try this response.[0].id

Comment: no. Can you tell me why is that when I add data type json it return no result?? Should I need to make any changes in controller??

Comment: it is working: var data = JSON.parse(response);
   name = data[0].card_name;
    $('#card_name').val(name) how can i do without data[0] ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185998/discussion-between-khagesh-and-haris-khan).

Answer (score 0):

In your other fields you can do the following in success method:

```
success: function(response) { 
  $('.input1').val(response.input1);
  $('.input2').val(response.input2);
  $('.label1').html(response.label1);
}
```

I hope it would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add unique ID property to your input like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text">
```

Then fill this input with ajax result by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

    var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
       //var id=$(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
              url: '/inquiryVendor',
              type: "Get",
              data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, // the value of input having id vid
               success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                $('#name').val(JSON.parse(response)[0].name); //<---- This line,

        }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Do this for all your input base you logic.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have input fields like this in your form

```
<input type="text" name="vendor_name" id="vendor_name">
<input type="text" name="vendor_mobile" id="vendor_mobile">
<input type="text" name="vendor_email" id="vendor_email">
```

You ajax code should be like this and I hope you get the parameters in your JSON response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

 var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
   //var id=$(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
          url: '/inquiryVendor',
          type: "Get",
          data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, // the value of input having id vid
           success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            $('#vendor_name').val(response.vendor_name)
            $('#vendor_mobile').val(response.vendor_mobile)
            $('#vendor_email').val(response.vendor_email) 
           }
        });
});
</script>
```

If this can't help then could you please do console.log(response) and paste the debug data so it will be easy to help you more.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#submitid').on('click', function() {

 var vid = $( "#vid" ).val();
   //var id=$(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
          url: '/inquiryVendor',
          type: "Get",
          data:{id:$("#vid").val()}, // the value of input having id vid
           success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            console.log(response)
           }
        });
});
</script>
```

if you don't want response[0] then you need to change in your controller File like this.

```
$vendor = DB::table('bp')->where('id', '.$id.')->first();
return response()->json($vendor);
```

As per your need, this will help for sure.

Comment: HI Vinod I did it but no response. please see the console response. I have edited question

Comment: I am getting values by using   $("#inputfieldid").val(response);  but not  $("#inputfieldid1").val(response.id);

Comment: Please update your code in ajax success like this it might help you.  $('#card_name').val(response[0].card_name)

Comment: yes with this it is working. Can you tell me how i can do this without [0]??